# Re- circulating system, one faucet gets cold

Tags: plumbing

I have one faucet at a bathtub that that starts hot but gets lukewarm after a few minutes. It is a newer faucet. Is it possible that I installed it incorrectly?

Comment: Need a little more info about your setup. Is the tub faucet strictly a hot water faucet or does it have a mixing valve to balance hot and cold? Brand and model? Describe the type of hot water recirculating system you have. Also you might want to [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll best know how to participate here.

Comment: Yes, we'll need more info.  One thing does come to mind. If the new faucet has a higher flow rate and you have an on-demand (tankless) water heater, the WH may not be able to produce enough hot water, fast enough to supply the new faucet.

Comment: Replacing a faucet it’s hard to do it wrong. ( hot is already on the left cold on the right). it sounds like an adjustment may be needed or a possibility something is plugging the cartridge I might check there first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In general, if the previous faucet did not have this issue, then you replaced the faucet, and everything else stayed the same, then you either have a dud valve or you did something wrong.

Now, if something changed, like rate of flow changed, then the issue may be with another component of the system.

Try posting a picture of the faucet and noting the make and model number, as well as pictures to show your piping supply lines.